# jsonschema dependentSchema not validating

Tags: jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I am trying to learn json schema, but something isn't working out for me.
I'm trying to run the example from http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html#id4 for **dependentSchemas**, but it just doesn't validate.

I'm using this schema:

```
check_schema = {"$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": { "type": "string" },
    "credit_card": { "type": "number" }
  },
  "required": ["name"],
  "dependentSchemas": {
    "credit_card": {
      "properties": {
        "billing_address": { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["billing_address"]
    }
  }
}
```

and this json, that should raise an error since it is missing the key `billing_address`:

```
check_dict={
  "name": "John Doe",
  "credit_card": 5555555555555555
}
```

but when I use `jsonschema.validate(dic_check, schema_check)` (with python, jsonschema package version 4.2.1), the validation passes with no issues.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks like you’re doing everything right here. Could you provide a small block of code to fully reproduce the issue please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using an implementation that doesn't support at least draft2019-09 of the specification, `dependentSchemas` won't be recognized as a keyword.  In earlier versions (draft7 and before), that keyword was known as `dependencies`, with the same syntax (actually, `dependencies` was split into two, `dependentSchemas` and `dependentRequired`).

The details are described on the page you linked, https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html#dependentschemas.

If you still believe that what you have should work, I suggest you open a bug report on the implementation's issue queue.

Comment: I tried changing to `dependencies`, but it didn't work. After reinstalling the package once again, it works. Thank you

Comment: I had this same problem, not sure if it was a pip/homebrew conflict. `brew reinstall jsonschema` and `brew link --overwrite jsonschema` fixed it